# Latex Image not showing up and rest of document doesnt either

Tags: graphics

The image is called corrected and it is in the image folder which is in the same directory as the tex file...what am I doing wrong? 
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{epsfig}

\textwidth 6.5truein          
\textheight 9.0truein
\oddsidemargin 0.0in
\topmargin -0.6in

\parindent 0pt          
\parskip 5pt
\def\baselinestretch{1.1}

\begin{document}

\begin{LARGE}
\centerline {\bf CSci 423 Corrections}
\end{LARGE}
\vskip 0.25cm
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{enumerate}
\item Homework 1: (9 points) Give the state diagram of a DFA (with 15 states) that recognizes the set of strings such that in each string the number of 0s is divisible by 5 and the number of 1s is divisible by 3.
\newline

\includegraphics{corrected}
\item Homework 1: (10 points) Prove by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\sum_{i=1}^n i)^2$.
\newline 

\newline 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Removing the `\newline` should eliminate the error.

Comment: don't load `epsfig` enless you have particular reason to use this emulation package of a latex2.09 package from the 1980's. don't use `true` dimensions in latex don't use `\bf` or `\centerline` (neither are really latex commands) don't end paragraphs with `\newline` or `\\ ` (none of these things will prevent the image appearing though:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the reason your image does not show up is that it is too wide, so in the MWE below I fixed the `width=6cm`:

[image]

### Notes:

- Instead of using `\newline`, you can use [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) to control the `itemsep` and `parsep` to achieve the desired additional spacing.
- As per @egreg's comments I have replaced `times` with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`, and removed epsfig` as it is obsolete and shouldn't be loaded in new documents.
- The image I am including below is quite wide. If I remove the `[width=6cm]` option to `\includegraphics` I obtain results similar to what you describe:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\textwidth 6.5truein          
\textheight 9.0truein
\oddsidemargin 0.0in
\topmargin -0.6in

\parindent 0pt          
\parskip 5pt
\def\baselinestretch{1.1}

\begin{document}

\begin{LARGE}
\centerline {\bf CSci 423 Corrections}
\end{LARGE}
\vskip 0.25cm
\graphicspath{{../images/}}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=10pt,parsep=10pt]
\item Homework 1: (9 points) Give the state diagram of a DFA (with 15 states) that recognizes the set of strings such that in each string the number of 0s is divisible by 5 and the number of 1s is divisible by 3.
%\newline

\includegraphics[width=6cm]{EiffelWide.jpg}
\item Homework 1: (10 points) Prove by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\sum_{i=1}^n i)^2$.
%\newline 

%\newline 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue, the problem still persists :(

Comment: @FullCombatBeard: Would be helpful if you provided more info. For instance, 1. What error messages are issued in the log file? 2. Does your code compile with the `\includegraphics{corrected}` line commented out? If so, then the problem is with the `\includegraphics`. 3. What kind of file is that you are trying to include?

Comment: Im trying to add a png file

There is no error, this is what is returned, my code compiles with or without the line in question: 
TraditionalBuilder: Invoking texify... done.

No errors.


[Done!]

Comment: @FullCombatBeard: Can you edit the question and explain what tool/OS you are using to compile this `.tex` file.  What about the other question: Does your code compile with the \includegraphics{corrected} line commented out?  Please add this info to the question as well.

Comment: `times` is obsolete and should be replaced by `mathptmx` (or, better, by `newtxtext` and `newtxmath). Also `epsfig` is obsolete and shouldn't be loaded in new documents.

Comment: My code does compile with the line commented out, it shows the entire document and not just the document up to that line

I am using latextools on sublime text on windows 8.1

Comment: @FullCombatBeard: Try adding the `width` option to `\includegraphics` as per the updated solution.  I was able to reproduce the problem you describe with a very wide image.